# Creating a mock for a global

Tags: typescript, jestjs, office-js

I wrote an add-in for Microsoft Office using the Office.js libraries and TypeScript. I'm using Jest to unit test it.

I'm running into issues where `@types/office-js` declares the type definitions where everything is behind global objects `Office` and `Word`. I can't seem to write a fake/mock implementation for these as they conflict with the type definitions. I also can't directly import or use Jest mock on `@microsoft/office-js` since it's not a real module - it's meant to be loaded by the browser in a script tag. When I run Jest, it does not resolve my new global namespaces - `ReferenceError: Word is not defined`.

Here's a simplified view of what I need to accomplish:

```
// __mocks__/word.ts
//@ts-ignore
export namespace Word {
    // stuff
}

// __tests__/something.ts
it('should find Word', () => Word...);
```

How can I create my fakes/mocks so that I can test the calls?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I tried one more thing.

I put

```
(<any>global).Word = Word;
```

at the bottom of `word.ts` and things seem happy.